# Viewdata sort on different column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my controller saving data from an stored SQL procedure into a Viewdata

```
        using (var SPOutput = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            foreach (var row in SPOutput)
            {
                outputmodel.Add(new SP_Procedure_RESULTS.student()
                {
                    student_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["student_id"],
                    age = (string)SPOutput4["age"],
                    course_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["course_id"],
                    building_no = (int)SPOutput4["building_no"],
                    room_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["room_id"],
                    status_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["status_id"],
                });

            }
            ViewData["Output"] = outputmodel;
```

but I would like to display them in my view in room_id (which is different for each row) order.
I have tried changing the last line to

```
ViewData["Output"] = new SelectList(outputmodel.OrderBy(x => x.room_id).ToList());
```

but , I then get a error in my view of

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

at the line

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_Procedure_RESULTS.student>)
```

Could someone show me how I can achieve changing the order in which the viewdata is displayed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer , and Future me, the code on the controller that works is :-

```
var order = outputmodel.OrderBy(c => c.room_no);
ViewData["Output"] = order;
```