# Need to select last ID from a viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewbag, viewdata

I have an ViewData with my production orders in it. Im doing a thing where the operator can create a new production by selecting the production order he wants to work on, but the ideal was to show already the last production order created, instead of him having to go across all the options and select the last one. Can someone help me out?

I'm working with ASP-NET C# Razor Pages.

This is my ViewData

```
 ViewData["production_order_ID"] = new SelectList(_context.Production_Order, "production_order_ID", "production_order_ID");
```

This is my page

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:10px">
                <label asp-for="Production.production_order_ID" class="control-label">Ordem de Produção:</label>
                <select id="orderList" name="ids" asp-for="Production.production_order_ID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.production_order_ID" onchange="getSensors(); myFunction(event);"></select>
            </div>
```

Now is showing the first item on the ViewData but i need to show the last one by default.

Comment: It may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730344/viewdata-sort-on-different-column

Comment: Why you don't want to use viewmodel instead of `ViewData` ?

Comment: Because it generated automatically and it's a custom page when i have like 4 different models and controllers in one, so i m just trying to put it all together and i thought ViewData is the best option for me. Although i can try other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what i just did was

`ViewData["production_order_ID"] = new SelectList(_context.Production_Order.Where(c => c.User.AspNetUser.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).OrderByDescending(c => c.production_order_ID).ToList(), "production_order_ID", "production_order_ID");`

and worked just fine for what i intended to. Sorry for wasting your time guys, but thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a viewmodel:

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public int Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action method create, popullate and pass the viewmodel into the view:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { OrderId = 1, OrderName = "Order # 1" },
        new Order { OrderId = 2, OrderName = "Order # 2" }
    };

    var viewModel = new OrdersViewModel() {
        Orders = orders,
        Selected = orders.LastOrDefault().OrderId    // get last order
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And the view:

```
@model MyWebApplication.Models.OrdersViewModel   // use your namespace

<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:10px">
    <label class="control-label">Ordem de Produção:</label>
    <select id="orderList" name="ids" asp-for="@Model.Selected" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Orders, "OrderId", "OrderName"))" onchange="getSensors(); myFunction(event);"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: But in that example i dont need to have "fixed" Orders? Cuz like the operator is able to create a lot of Orders and everytime it creates a new one it goes to the ViewData, in that case i wanted to go to the List. But by doing "new Order .... " I'm stop that from happening. ( Btw sry for the newbie questions, im new to the programming world so i have really difficulties on basic stuff)